# Save Unity canvas as a PNG file

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

Is there a way to convert a canvas from my scene in Unity project into PNG file?
I don't want to use cameras and screenshots because i need non conventional resolution of that canvas.

Comment: You should be able to render any resolution you want with a second camera and a render texture.

Comment: Thanks, thats very true. Camera compoenent also has some float properties in 'Viewport Rect' section that can cause canvas to change aspect ratio.